# « With naive recursion » : de quelle récursion s'agit-il et comment l'introduire ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, prépositions, informatique, formulation-idiomatique

Dans une réponse [ailleurs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39132127) on dit « [...] you can rewrite the problem with **naive recursion** ». Le contexte c'est un langage de programmation qui ne dispose pas d'une instruction intégrée [*for/while*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion) pour faire une boucle. En comparant avec un autre contexte d'emploi de l'adjectif [*naive*](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/naive) on trouve un certain nombre de [termes](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26510480) (*élémentaire, simpliste* etc.).

Quel terme préfère-t-on ; avec quelle préposition va-t-on l'introduire ; va-t-on l'employer avec « une [récursion](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%A9cursion) » (ou un autre substantif sur la même base) avec ou sans le mot *fonction* pour formuler une traduction de la phrase en question [« on peut reformuler/réécrire [...] avec/en/à... »] ou pour désigner ce dont il s'agit ?

Answer (score 2):

> <s>Avec une simple récursion</s>

> Avec une récursion toute bête

Nouvelle suggestion suite aux commentaires :

> [...] tu peux réécrire le problème en t'appuyant sur une récursion naïve.

Comment: D'accord, merci, dirais-tu aussi _récursion simple_ avec le même sens ?

Comment: Pas tout à fait. La forme préfixée met plus l'emphase sur le fait que c'est suffisant, qu'on n'a pas besoin de chercher plus loin. *Un simple choix* : un seul choix, *un choix simple* : pas compliqué.

Comment: Ok, mais je comprends mal d'abord, comment qualfierais-tu une récursion qui s'appuie sur l'instruction _for_ ? C'est que je vois _naive_ ni comme une épithète pure ni _naive recursion_ comme une abtraction pure mais la personne qui a dit ça n'a pas mis de déterminant (_a_) devant _naive_ de sorte que pour moi ça ajoute du poids au mot composé dans le sens d'un concept/sujet. Je veux pouvoir disserter de ça et j'ai comme un doute, remarque le doute est peut-être davantage tributaire du fait que ce n'est pas mon domaine, comme on sait.

Comment: Ah oui, je n'avais pas vraiment fait attention à l'absence d'article devant *naive*. Ma réponse ne tient plus la route. Il semble bien s'agir d'un concept des langages fonctionnels (pas mon truc non plus). Autant traduire par *récursion naïve* dans ce cas.

Comment: Récursion *intuitive/instinctive*, celle qui tous les débutants de "Hello World" on “créé” … if … goto …

Comment: @Personne Il y a de ça, on pourrait ajouter *une récursion lourdingue*, peut-être...

Comment: Pas vraiment, … if … goto n'a rien de lourdingue en soit, cette récursion appartient au vocabulaire de l'école primaire du *geek*, mais tout le monde peut la comprendre ; elle est bien moins lourdingue/illisible que l'assembleur … alors on pourrait dire ***récursion primaire*** —  j'avais pensé à *primitive* (relative aux arts et instruments premiers de l'Homme des cavernes), mais c'est une notion mathématique … et primaire à peut-être des connotations dans certaines régions de la francophonie. Quant aux récursions élégantes, en dehors du *loop* simpliste, peu de génies savent les maintenir.

Comment: @Personne Lourdingue dans le sens où elle n'est pas optimisée, que son exécution est lourde.

Comment: Moi aussi j'ai pensé à _primitive_, mais dans mon cas j'aime bien le lexique des maths. C'est pour ça que j'aime aussi _élémentaire_ ou _logique_ même. En fait peut-être même _mathématique_ presque, vu peut-être la nature de Haskell (je ne sais pas) et le contexte. Plus encore bien l'étiquette du nom de l'instruction n'est peut-être pas très pertinente en soi, je veux dire _for/while_ ce n'est pas un concept. Ça renvoye à la boucle, une boucle fait appel à la récursivité. Peut-être même qu'il faut aller dans le sens contraire avec _formelle_. C'est _for_ qui représente une simplification...

Comment: La "naive recursion" de la réponse est une implémentation qui n'utilise pas de boucle for ou while mais du code qui s'appuie sur la récursivité, et ce qui est "naif", c'est que la méthode utilisée n'est pas efficace, d'où mon "lourdingue".